# Using InstallShield 2011, how can one create an installation to add files to a previously installed program?

Tags: installshield, installshield-2011

I've written an add-in to an existing program.  I want to create an installation which copies files to a sub-folder within the previously installed program folder.  The installation path of the existing program is available in the registry.

- Can one do this using InstallShield 2011?
- If so, please tell me how, or give me a link to a document which explains how.

Thanks,
Stephen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new QuickPatch project, and use the MSI from the previous installation.